# Access bean name in custom method interceptor

Tags: spring, interceptor, spring-aop

I want to write bean name and method executed in database so decide to create an custom interceptor. However, I am not able to access the bean name.

I found ExposeBeanNameAdvisors may be one of the solution, but not able to find a point to set the name.

Anyone have the ideas about this? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make your beans to implement a BeanNameAware interface.